# Have notification bars gone wonky after recent failover tests?

Tags: bug, notifications, top-bar

Since yesterday's downtime, my notification bar indicates one unread message, always. Opening the dropdown shows that all messages are read. The indicator resets when the dropdown closes then, but reappears when the next page is loaded.

Notifications about reputation changes are apparently not visible on the bar anymore.

Logging out and back in has not had any effect, nor did a switch to a different browser.

Have you guys faced similar issues?

Comment: My notification and inbox indicators are also stuck.

Comment: And... it seems to be fixed now? It's really strange.

Comment: @Lekensteyn not fixed yet, it's very unstable.

Comment: @Mat Unlike that question, I never get any notifications no matter how many times I refresh the page.

Comment: I am having a stuck New reputation changes notification on different sites. I can click through to the subject of the notification (e.g. clicking the link for "+10 for BLAH"), but as soon as I click any other link, the notification is back.

Comment: @Felix: just depends on if you had any notifications at the moment of the downtime. Status is frozen in that state. It's the same problem, reported 15 times here already, and as many times on MSO.

Comment: @Mat indeed, sorry for the noise then. My search terms were obviously flawed. Lots of "me too", no solution yet. Guess we'll have to wait and see.